# Is it possible to track if the viewer on my site likes it?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, web-deployment

my purpose to make something similar like "Pay with a Tweet", but the spread is, that you just have to like the site before you get an coupon.

Any idea for the technical implementation is welcome.

Comment: Stackoverflow if to help with code-related questions. This isn't the free do-this-for-me centre.

Comment: I thought someone had already experience with similar stuff, or i get a hint in with direction i have to go.

Comment: Are we talking about a website or a facebook app?`

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe the the right event, fire a AJAX-Request.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

The like runs in the browser, so you have afaik no chance - without reloading to check wether the user liked it.

Doing it with the PHP SDK is an option too. Reload the page (with the JS SDK) and check in the PHP SDK wether the page is liked.

Do whatever you want with this information